# Pulsing circle before the post title (Breaking news flash)

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I want to add a pulsing circle before the post title on my news site.

When I create a new post I want a check button.
If i checked it then there would show a pulsing circle before the title of the post.
If it`s unchecked then the pulsing circle is off, and the title is standard.

Anyone with an idea how i easy can fix this ?
Some CSS maybe ?

Most ideal is an automatic function for when the post is not the top post of my site anymore the pulsing circle is not showing.

Comment: What are your results so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I have the idea and know what I want, but don't quite know how to do it.
What is the best / easiest way. Use CSS or make a plugin ?

I have only seen large news company use this on breaking news.

I thought it would be nice to have it on my little online news site too.

Comment: You will need a plugin to insert this feature independent of the theme. The plugin will have to generate the checkbox in the backoffice, insert in the theme and add some css to make it visible. If you do not know how to do this, your best option is to hire a developer.